# Word error :the file cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.The file is corruted

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, xslt-1.0, docx

I generated a new xml file by using XSLT transformation and then replaced the file `document.xml` (which is my generated version of XML file) in place of the one where I have the zip extracted xml word file. WHen I zip all the contents back to the word file and then change the extension from `zip to docx and open the file`, I get the above error. I have been trying since  a day and was unable to find the issue. BUt when it asks to `recover` the file and I say yes, then the `docx` file opens with no problems.

Any suggetsions?

Comment: Is there any kind of CRC or other way Word uses to see if the file contents have changed?

Comment: @StanleyDeBoer  I could use altova XMLspy to compare the repaired doc and the corrupted doc...I tried this but in my implementation context not able to find the exact fix for the error!!

Comment: I don't mean there is anything your with `document.xml`, but if your docx is anything like mine there are lots of files. Word might check them for consistency and if there is anything that doesn't match it says it is corrupted. Specifically I was looking at `docProps/app.xml` and `core.xml`.

Comment: Could you please send us the generated docx document (the one that is corrupted), or at least the files you have changed ? What tags do you use ? Do you add images or something more complex ?

Comment: @edi9999 u r absolutely right...I do changes in the rels file by adding images and also hyperlinks..but when i zip all the word files and convert it to docx, then say recover the file everything works well!!

Comment: @StanleyDeBoer hmm that might be true..But as per my knowledge i  do not think it might be an issue... I might be wrong!!

Comment: Could you please post your rel file and the content of the image folder ?

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question ?